# Place custom content field only on sidebar

Tags: 7, theming, entities, nodes

i have created a custom content type "My_Content" with some custom fields. One of the fields in "My_field". Now, when the user is creating a content of type My_content, he/she is asked for the fields like title, body, picture, My_field etc...What i need is that the My_field always displays on the right sidebar. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module.  From the Page Manager configuration screen (Pages in the admin interface), enable the node edit page override.  Then edit this override.

Create a new variant.  Set the selection rule to be "content has type" -> "my custom content type".  Then, under Layout, choose an appropriate layout (one with a right sidebar).

Afterwards, under content, you will need to add all of the fields for the content type to be edited.  Just place My_field in the right sidebar and it will be displayed there.

Comment: ...can you do so by any other method, say through. The reason i ask this is because when i am using Panel and overriding then my flags which i placed on nodes of that particular content type (using **Flag** module) are gone, i.e, they are not being displayed.

Comment: I checked again..the flags are displaying on other content types but not here

Comment: Hey..i solved that issue...just needed to add        `<?php print flag_create_link('bookmarks', %node:nid); ?>`                                                       inside Add custom content under Add content in the Panel